# Elements of $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, notation

I want to find the elements in the set of rotational symmetries of a tetrahedron by its labeled edges that produce 12 elements within $S_6$

So, how do I notate those permutations of the edges? Normally cycle notation is based on vertices.

Comment: Cycle notation is based on a labeling of whatever objects you are acting on. Just label the edges and use those labels to identify a cycle representation of your rotation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so I did that, but I'm not able to find 12 such symmetries.  I'm able to create cycles out of e, r, rr, s, etc., but these involve product of reflections and rotations. In order to have 12 rotations I'd need to fix an edge, but that's not possible

Answer (score 1):

Rotations by $120^{\circ}$ around a each vertex permute the edges in two groups of three, so you end up with the identity and eight elements that are products of two disjoint cycles.

Now visualize the tetrahedron with one edge horizontal facing you, and one edge vertical away from you. A rotation of $180^{\circ}$ degrees around the centers of both these edges map these two edges to themselves, and permutes the remaining four edges in two exchanges of two edges. So you get a permutation that is a product of two disjoint transpositions. There are three such pairs of edges you can fix. Added to the nine permutations you already had, this gives you all twelve permutations. Just label the edges to get the specific permutations.

You can see that rotation using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/PgyzAXRP).